# Woocommerce Storefront Theme remove "shipping may be available" text on cart page and checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I would like to remove the text "shipping may be available" on my cart and checkout page. I have attached an image and circled in red what I would like removed.

[Text to be removed circled in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2Dcw.jpg)

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please post what you attempted to solved the problem so far. Just saying "I have a problem, please solve it" is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like an idiot- woocommerce was able to help me and it was a very simple solution- just some simple CSS:

```css
.pickup-location-field small {
    display: none;
}
```